# Why GCC doesn't report any errors or warnings when using WinAPI: COLORREF/RGB?

Tags: c, winapi, mingw32

The correct usage is:

```
COLORREF COLOR = RGB (255,255,255);
```

However, This

```
COLORREF COLOR = (255,255,255);
```

can be compiled without any warnings or errors.

Why? So strange? Thanks.

### Reference:

1. [COLORREF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183449(v=vs.85).aspx)
2. [RGB()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162937(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type `COLORREF` is a typedef for a `DWORD`. The line

```
COLORREF COLOR = (255,255,255);
```

is equivalent to

```
DWORD COLOR = 255;
```

and therefore compiles fine. It may not do what you want however.

The reason is that `expr1, expr2` yields the value of `expr2` in C, so `255, 255, 255` has a value of `255`. The brackets have no effect here. See:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

Note that the RGB macro itself just makes the appropriate `DWORD` (some number) from red, green and blue components. Numbers essentially *are* COLORREFs here.

Comment: Thx, but why not declare COLORREF as a structure? ie. `typedef struct _COLORREF { BYTE RED, BYTE GREEN, BYTE BLUE } COLORREF;` I think that declaring COLORREF as a structure is much better, isn't it?